# Removed pages. set them 404 or 301 to home page?

Tags: seo, redirects, 404

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SEO: ecommerce item deleted by user, 301 redirect to HOME PAGE or 404 not found?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5392/seo-ecommerce-item-deleted-by-user-301-redirect-to-home-page-or-404-not-found)

I decided to delete about 2000 pages because of panda update.

Should I just set them 404 or redirect them to home page with 301 ?

Answer (score 3):

Do a 404 error.  The pages are missing so that is what you should report.  Make a customized 404 error page with links to a sitemap or a search form to help people find the new content.

301 redirect are for content that has moved, which is not the case here.