# Moving commerce products from one domain to another

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, ecommerce, 404

I'm the developer for a small online webstore - surfhq.co.uk. We've just moved a subsection of products (the bodyboarding products), off surfhq.co.uk on to bodyboardhq.co.uk to sell them there instead.

We didn't want to sell on both stores as search engines don't like duplicate pages - and bodyboardhq.co.uk has much better seo for bodyboarding - the site has been run as an active blog for sometime - we've only just added the cart.

My question is, should I be using a 301 redirect on the old product pages (sending users to the new pages on bodyboardhq.co.uk), or should I just serve up a 404 not found? Google search currently lists a lot of broken links (I've gone down the 404 route for fear that permanent redirects will result in one of our sites being penalised).

My question is not answered [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5392/ecommerce-item-deleted-by-user-301-rediret-to-home-page-or-404-not-found) where the 301 is to the home page and the products have been deleted. My products have been moved to another domain (the 301 would be to the product on the new domain). Also I'm concerned with the SEO effect on both domains.

Comment: Please do not re-ask questions that were closed.

Comment: @JohnConde please re-open the original question.