# Updating all website url to contain a slash at the end

Tags: seo, google-analytics, canonical-url

For some technical reasons, one of the websites I am currently working with have to change it's url pattern from `www.example.com/about` to `www.example.com/about/`

This website is already indexed by Google, so what would be the best way to go with this process?

Add canonical link to all pages indicating previous(`www.example.com/about`) urls ?
Or is there any way to do this without getting hit by Google for duplicate contents.

Comment: See also: [Does it make a difference if your URL path ends in a trailing slash or not?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/does-it-make-a-difference-if-your-url-path-ends-in-a-trailing-slash-or-not)

Comment: See also: [How to retain/transfer ranking when updating/redesigning website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/how-to-retain-transfer-ranking-when-updating-redesigning-website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that Google transfers your link juice to the new trailing-slash page after your content is no longer available at the version without the trailing slash, you need to:

1. 301-redirect all of your non-slash pages to the version with the trailing slash. Many web server softwares will do this automatically.
2. (optional) Add a canonical tag to each page that *includes* the trailing slash (the canonical tag should always contain the current canonical URL of the page).

You will not "get hit" by Google for duplicate content. See [The myth of the duplicate content penalty - Search Engine Land](https://searchengineland.com/myth-duplicate-content-penalty-259657). Google chooses the version of your page that it deems to be canonical (the redirect and/or canonical tag lets you specify which one you want), then Google will index that version of the page without any issue or penalty.